# How can I run bitcoind and bitcoinclassicd on the same server?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, bitcoin-classic

I want to run full nodes for Bitcoin (bitcoind) and Bitcoin cash ([bitcoinclassic](https://bitcoinclassic.com/)). Here are the commands I'm using to run these nodes (I've renamed bitcoin classic tools to `bitcoinclassic*` and moved the executables to the `/usr/bin`):

```
$ bitcoind -daemon -dbcache=3072 -rpcthreads=10
$ bitcoinclassicd -daemon -datadir=.bitcoinclassic/ -dbcache=3072 -rpcthreads=10
```

They are both starts OK, but when I'm trying to use the bitcoin-cli and bitcoinclassic-cli, for some reason I'm getting information only for bitcoinclassic

```
$ bitcoin-cli getinfo
{
  "version": 1030300,
  "protocolversion": 80002,
  "walletversion": 130000,
  "balance": 0.00000000,
  "blocks": 479637,
  "timeoffset": 0,
  "connections": 19,
  "proxy": "",
  "difficulty": 115459053827.9121,
  "testnet": false,
  "keypoololdest": 1502885275,
  "keypoolsize": 101,
  "paytxfee": 0.00000000,
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "errors": ""
}

$ bitcoinclassic-cli getinfo
{
  "version": 1030300,
  "protocolversion": 80002,
  "walletversion": 130000,
  "balance": 0.00000000,
  "blocks": 479637,
  "timeoffset": 0,
  "connections": 19,
  "proxy": "",
  "difficulty": 115459053827.9121,
  "testnet": false,
  "keypoololdest": 1502885275,
  "keypoolsize": 101,
  "paytxfee": 0.00000000,
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "errors": ""
}
```

How can I fix it? Maybe I should use more flags at the start, e.g. specifying configuration file or something else?

UPDATE: I forget to say, that they are not using the same port, here's the configs:

```
$ cat .bitcoin/bitcoin.conf 
rpcuser=USER
rpcpassword=PASS
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcport=8332
server=1
$ cat .bitcoinclassic/bitcoin.conf 
rpcuser=USER
rpcpassword=PASS
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcport=8432
server=1
bind=0.0.0.0:9222
maxconnections=10
```

Comment: Are they using the same RPC port?

Comment: @NickODell no, check question's update

Comment: Are you using -conf to tell each cli tool where to find the configuration for that daemon?

Comment: @NickODell No, I thought that they will try to find configuration files in their datadir folders (.bitcoin and .bitcoinclassic). Should I do it?

Comment: Let me rephrase - are you using -datadir to tell each cli tool where to find the configuration for that daemon?

Comment: @NickODell As I wrote in my question, I'm using -datadir option with bitcoinclassicd (-datadir=.bitcoinclassic/). I'm not using this flag with bitcoind, so it's using default folder (.bitcoin).

Comment: Are you passing the -datadir option to bitcoinclassic-cli?

Comment: @NickODell nope. I've tried - didn't help.

Comment: Sergey, have you found what caused the trouble?